# CSS - on hover, highlight element (as well as inner element)

Tags: css

I'm using font-icons, and I am trying to get the icon as well as the `<a>` tags around it to change color when hovered over.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.container a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color cubic-bezier(.170, .70, .49, 1) .5s,
    color cubic-bezier(.170, .70, .49, 1) .3s;
}
```

So when the `<a>` tags are hovered over, I want the `<a>` tag as well as the inner `<i>` tags to change color, with the `<a>` getting its `background-color` changed, and `<i>` having its `color` changed. I've tried the following:

```
.container a:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: red;
}
```

This will get the `background-color` to change to purple on hover, but the `<i>` tags inside the `<a>` tags will not change to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not selecting the `<i>`.

```
.container a:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: red;
}

.container a:hover > i {
    color: red;
}
```

You'll have to select the `<i>` inside the `<a>`